Mesh has no smoothing groups (Blend Shape Avatar)
I have not been able to figure out this problem for a week now, I searched the entire Internet and did not find any solution.
After configuring Shape Keys in Blender (4.0) and exporting.fbx file in Unity (2022.3.24f1) when setting up the VRM already, my model does not blink its eyes, but simply deforms the texture. I have tried various options and still nothing helps, despite the fact that everything works in Blender itself and blinking occurs without defects.
I also have VRM packages installed that are needed
Also sometimes I get an error in the console
Can't generate normals for blendshape ''on mesh '', mesh has no smoothing groups

The screenshot showing the problem
shape
This problem occurs with any of my models

i have the same issue, the mesh also move upwards for some reason despite it being ok in blender, I figured you can fix the error in the console by joining all the mesh with ctrl j but the problem with the blendshapes is still there.

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review
